# Java template Framework which has placeholder syntax as {{firstName}}

Tags: java, templates, velocity, freemarker, template-engine

I've a template which has the placeholder syntax in `{{firstName}}` format. Which templating framework supports this kind of syntax?

I've seen Apache Velocity uses `${firstName}` format. If there is anyway to change the syntax in velocity to `{{firstName}}` instead of `${}`, that will also help me.

Comment: [Handlebars.java](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java)?

Comment: AngularJS? What's the file extension of the file? Is this part of your project? Is it *definitely* a Java template?

Comment: thanks, will checkout the Handlebars.java for branch conditions and loops.

Comment: @Romski, Its a HTML, there we need to substitute the placeholders in the java side.. its not AngularJS. Template development is being done by other team.

Comment: Have you asked the other team? Maybe they expect you to use a particular engine, or maybe they expect you to edit those files and replace the placeholders with markup appropriate for your project.

Comment: The content development team won't change the syntax as they follow the same for many years. About replace - its not just placeholder substitution, we will also have branch(if & else) and loops(for, while) in the template. As of now, Handlebars.java seems to fine, will post the update.

Answer (score 0):

Both [handlebars](https://jknack.github.io/handlebars.java/) and [mustache](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) have Java implementations, and they use the double curly brace syntax.

Velocity does not support that syntax, and you can't make it, but converting between different template languages is often very easy. Search and replace can get you a long way.